# Why are some objects not converting from Illustrator to CAD?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, file-conversion, autocad

Apologies, if I am missing the obvious, I am new to both AutoCAD and Illustrator.

I have drawn up a design in Illustrator to be converted into `.dwg` to be used in AutoCAD. These designs were drawn using the pen tool and then expanded, all elements of the design (aside from a logo which has not been an issue) were drawn and converted in this same way.

However, after conversion there are three lines in the Illustration that have repeatedly failed to convert and do not show up in the drawing. I have checked that they are expanded in the same way, I have copied them into other parts of the design in the hopes of moving them back later, I drew them in the exact same way as the rest of the converted design, but they disappear the moment I go from Illustrator to `.dwg`.

I am wondering if there are any other parameters I should check?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Impossible to say there is no info to use for a solution

Comment: The *only* possible way to solve this is to examine the objects and determine what makes them different from other objects. It must be something. There's no way anyone here can examine the objects.

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned before I am new to both the softwares and this forum, if there is something else I need to upload I would be happy to do so if you can tell me exactly what that is and how. For the initial question I was mainly just asking for troubleshooting advice and if anyone knew the parameters for conversion so that I can check myself, if this is not possible then I would happily take any other advice to make my question clearer.

Comment: It might help to look in your layers panel to see if the round dots next to the object was filled, or if the object has transparency. Anyway its impossible to answer the question:  "my car is broken but nothing is wrong with it" you need to describe what you have. Clearly something is different you just dont know what that is. So its not just that we are skeptical, we know that what you say is somehow not correct.